# Script tag is not loading "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" content

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js project and want to add google analytics code. I have put that code in _app.js file like mentioned [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-analytics). By running code, I am not able to view the code which I have inserted in "dangerouslySetInnerHTML".

Here is my code in _app.js

`<Script strategy="beforeInteractive" id="gtag-init" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "code"}} />`

Comment: Is your code exactly the same as in the example you link to? If not, can you please post the full code in your `_app` file?

Comment: @juliomalves, I have javascript code given by my client which I have to put. So I have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. But when I run the project I am not able to see the script in the inspect elements.

Comment: Can you post the full code in your `_app` file?

Comment: I have solved it by using the <script> tag. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Please use afterInteractive strategy like this: `strategy="afterInteractive"`

See next.js documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#afterinteractive

> Examples of scripts that are good candidates to load immediately after
> the page becomes interactive include:
>
> Tag managers
>
> Analytics

Comment: I tried with that also. But didn't work.